# Can a dry suit exist for a furred creature?

Tags: underwater, clothing

Broadly speaking, a [dry suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_suit) is a garment which restricts fluid exchange between the portion of the body covered and the outside environment. These work for humans because it is not unreasonably difficult to achieve a water-resistant seal between the suit material and human skin. (Yes, there are also varieties which completely surround the wearer, but for my purposes I am not interested in that method.)

Alas, people in my world have fur.

They still want dry suits; both for the reasons humans would, and also for other purposes, e.g. the ability to go swimming while needing to protect *limited* parts of the body from water (e.g. due to injuries or... [other reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kink_(sexuality)), and because this is a harder problem then creating a fully-enclosed suit).

Rules:

- The garment must not require the user to shave; my people's vanity will not stand for such an offense (and it would be very inconvenient).
- Putting on the garment should be relatively easy. Having to part fur to get a good seal is fine. Having to put special goop in one's fur (as long as it will washes out again!) is less desirably, but not categorically unacceptable.
- The garment should restrict ingress to 100 mL or less given a "seam" length of 1 m (e.g. around the waist) and an expected 4-5 hours of use.
- The above only needs to be accomplished to a maximum depth of 5m. (However, if it won't work up to at least 15m, please show why. I'm more interested in swimming pools than deep diving, though.)
- Gravity, pressure, etc. are approximately Earth-normal (close enough to make little difference, anyway). For the purposes of this question, something that would work on a roughly-human-sized animal on Earth is acceptable.

Is a dry suit — or, more generally, a water-resistant seal between a garment and the wearer's *fur-covered* body — still possible, strictly according to science? If "no", but if I also have magic that can continuously repel water with a force of 10 N, does that help?

Answer (score 7):

**Vaseline**

Your creature's vanity be damned, your only option other than shaving is to use a gel such as Vaseline to create a gasket the suit can bond to. The seals will still need to be tight and you will always have a pressure limitation that's less than what could be achieved with skin alone — but it would work.

The gel would need to be worked into the fur such that it coated the fur to the skin and was wider than the seal band on both the inside and the outside.

**Then add a vacuum**

On top of this, design the seals to produce a vacuum. It need not be electrical. A lever (not unlike those found on suction cups) would be enough. Removing the oxygen within the seal would improve the quality of the seal (like suction cups). If you adopt this aspect, the seals would need to be flexible enough to form to the shape of the body.

Comment: Otters.........

Answer (score 4):

### The same way as thinly haired humans do.

(Assuming of course that when you say 'furred' you mean a normal layer of fur as per the average animal not thick fur like that of a yak, polar bear or lions mane etc.)

Just use slightly longer and (more importantly) *tighter* neoprene, silicon or latex seals where needed as well as a thick layer of Vaseline rubbed into the fur under the seals. And go with one piece dry suits and one piece neoprene undergarments. Between the undergarment and the fur your characters should stay warmer and dryer than normal divers because all fur is slightly water resistant and provides an extra layer of insulation via the air it traps.

But remember normal dry suits do leak at least a *little* because the water tight seals are never perfect.